# End If without block If - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Getting "Type mismatch" error on the following code and cannot figure this one out...

```
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Front Wing" Or "Nose" Or _
   ActiveSheet.Name = "Bargeboard" Or _
   ActiveSheet.Name = "Sidepod Vane" Or _
   ActiveSheet.Name = "Fwd Floor" Then

Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Front Team Project List")
    With ws
        For Each aCell In .Range(Sheets("Front Team Project List").Cells(2, ProjectColumn), _
               Sheets("Front Team Project List").Cells(ProjectRangeLastRow, ProjectColumn))
            If aCell.Value <> "" Then
                Me.ComboBoxProjectTitle.AddItem aCell.Value
            End If
        Next
    End With
End If
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: On your first line, delete the `_` at the end.

Comment: Side note - you can't use `Or` like that - you have to repeat the condition part. `If ActiveSheet.Name = "Front Wing" Or ActiveSheet.Name = "Bargeboard"...`. This is a good case for `Select Case`.

Comment: `Each aCell In .Range(Sheets("VBA_Data").Cells(2, ProjectColumn), Sheets("VBA_Data").Cells(ProjectRangeLastRow, ProjectColumn))` this is problematic. The outer `Range` and the inner `Cells` refer to different sheets. That will blow up right away.

Comment: Thanks All. Damian - I have removed the "_" from this line, and modified to repeat the condition part as per suggestion from BigBen, now I am getting a "Type Mismatch" error on the top line (nothing to do with repeating the condition part as it throws the error with or without that change)

Comment: Maybe [edit] your question with the revised code you are using.

Comment: Done this now BigBen

Comment: `If ActiveSheet.Name = "Front Wing" Or "Nose"`... you missed one instance of `ActiveSheet.Name =`.

Comment: You're still going to have to fix the 4th line too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the first lines into the following and it works:

```
If ActiveSheet.Name = "Front Wing" Or _
   ActiveSheet.Name = "Nose" Or _
   ActiveSheet.Name = "Bargeboard" Or _
   ...
```